# Will it enough only to include the Apache license file in the source code in android kotlin application?

Tags: apache-2.0, license, android

I have been implementing an Android application using Kotlin and thought of using the KOIN library for dependency injection. However, it is licensed under the Apache 2.0 license which has become a huge concern to me since I am unaware of what steps I need to follow to abide by its terms and conditions.

I've included the link for their license file:
https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/main/LICENSE

What I really want to know is whether it is enough to include the license file in the source code when pushing the application to the play store, considering the application just has a single activity with a webview (No place to show the open source licenses)?

Comment: Why can you not link to the open source licenses in your webview?

Comment: You may have to add a "about" dialog to your app in which you show the licensing information (including your own license).